# Do "Clean Code"'s function argument number guidelines apply to constructors?

Tags: java, function, methods

Chapter 3 of "Clean Code" makes it pretty clear that keeping the number of function arguments small is good practice. I'm now trying to avoid anything beyond dyads. It's been working out ok so far but I keep running into situations where I need three arguments to construct an object. Of course I could create an argument object to solve this but then I'd have to choose two of the three arguments to group together and that does not always make sense. So my question is if this guideline applies to constructors as well or if I shouldn't worry about triad constructors.

Comment: Constructors are just special methods. This advice applies equally to constructors.

Comment: The "rule" does not apply whenever doing something else would result in cleaner code. The same is true for all other advice in the book.

Comment: if constructor needs more than a handful of parameters and most of them are optional then we need to use `Builder` pattern

Comment: @TanmoyMajumdar Even if none of the arguments are optional and there are only three of them?

Comment: In addition to the builder pattern mentioned above, another potential way to reduce the number of parameters is to create dedicated classes to sub-sets of parameters. For example if you have a `Person` then instead of passing in `city`, `streetName`, `streetNumber`, pass in an `Address` object.

Comment: @2um9YJ6haZ7wKP4m: if the rules says "less than 3" and you get a simple class that takes exactly 3 easily distinguishable parameters, then let there be 3. Don't bend over backwards to follow the letter of the rule, care about the intent.

Comment: This is very subjective and answers will be opinion-based. Good practices are nice but those are not meant to be unbreakable laws. In my opinion, there is no reason not to put 3 or more arguments in a constructor or a method if I need them and they wouldn't fit in a class.

Comment: Creating a special class receiving N args because you don't want the method to receive those N args is not a solution, it just moves the complexity to another place

Comment: @2um9YJ6haZ7wKP4m it depends. if there is only there parameters and none of them are optional and they clearly define the object then I guess it's safe to use. But if it does not define the object properly then a static factory method will be good. For example BigInteger class has a static factory method `probablePrime` which defines the object properly

Comment: @JoachimSauer Yes, that's what I meant by argument objects. But sometimes you have three arguments and there is no obvious way of grouping two of them. You could create an argument object for all three of them but then you'd have a constructor with three arguments again. EDIT: Just saw your second comment. We are in agreement.

Comment: IMO you are asking the wrong question. It's not whether a constructor can have three arguments, it's whether a class should be dependent on three other classes; because that's what a constructor does, it initializes the minimum members that are necessary for the class to function.

Comment: @daniu I see your point but three constructor arguments does not necessarily mean being dependent on three other classes. Two or all three arguments could have the same type.

Answer (score 0):

These "rules" are guidelines and it depends on the use case. In general, it's a good idea to keep the number of arguments low. Besides using composite types as arguments, there are some common patterns for this:

The classic [builder pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern), or what I prefer, the modern variation [fluent builder pattern](https://dzone.com/articles/fluent-builder-pattern)

E.g.:

```
Email email = Email.EmailBuilder()
              .setFrom("Test@gmail.com")
              .setTo("mail@gmail.com")
              .setSubject("Test with only required Fields")
              .setContent(" Required Field Test")
              .build();
```

Comment: Using builders doesn't prevent multiple arguments on the constructor, because the `.build()` method will call the class constructor internally, and pass all those parameters still.